# Addition to the flags

Tags: feature-request

There should be a flag to raise complaints like:

1) Lacks research efforts

2) Transfer to Chemistry SE

Like this question:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/276969/how-supersonic-plan-could-create-shock-wave

Comment: Just downvote and vote to close. No extra flags needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1) Lacks research efforts

Currently, this is not something to be flagged. Just downvote.

> 2) Transfer to Chemistry SE

For this one, if you really have reason to believe the question would be on topic at Chemistry (for instance, you are a regular participant on that site and you know their scope), just use a custom moderator flag with wording like the following:

> Off topic here, but may be suitable for migration to Chemistry

If you're not sure whether it would be on topic there, just choose "Blatantly off topic". Those who have enough reputation to vote to close with a custom off-topic reason can do that instead. I recommend the following wording:

> I'm voting to close this question as off topic because it's about chemistry, not physics or astronomy. It may be appropriate on [chemistry.SE].